# Hibernate aliasToBean does not convert string to Enum

Tags: hibernate, enums, hql

I have the query below that is selecting a constant in the column list and I was expecting aliasToBean to convert the string to the appropriate enum type.

I have mapped other entities with enum properties as Strings and not had any problems.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<AssociatedEntity> fileList = queryUtil.createHQLQuery((
            "select '" + AssociatedEntityTypeEnum.ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_TYPE_FILE + "' as associatedEntityType," +
            " a.file2Id as id," +
            " f.name as name" +
            " from File f, Association a" +
            " where f.id = :fileId" +
            " and a.file1Id = f.id" +
            " and a.associationType = :associationType"
    ))
    .setParameter("fileId", fileId)
    .setParameter("associationType", AssociationTypeEnum.ASSOCIATION_TYPE_FILE_FILE)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AssociatedEntity.class))
    .list();
```

This is the bean:

```
public class AssociatedEntity {

public AssociatedEntity() {}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private AssociatedEntityTypeEnum associatedEntityType;
public AssociatedEntityTypeEnum getAssociatedEntityType() { return this.associatedEntityType; }
public void setAssociatedEntityType(AssociatedEntityTypeEnum associatedEntityType) { this.associatedEntityType = associatedEntityType; }

private Integer id;
public Integer getId() { return this.id; }
public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

private String name;
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
public String getName() { return this.name; }

}
```

and here are the errors:

```
23.11.2011 17:05:25  INFO [http-8080-2] (QueryUtil:createHQLQuery) - select 'ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_TYPE_FILE' as associatedEntityType, a.file2Id as id, f.name as name from File f, Association a where f.id = :fileId and a.file1Id = f.id and a.associationType = :associationType
23.11.2011 17:05:25 ERROR [http-8080-2] (BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter:set) - IllegalArgumentException in class: com.twoh.dto.AssociatedEntity, setter method of property: associatedEntityType
23.11.2011 17:05:25 ERROR [http-8080-2] (BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter:set) - expected type: com.twoh.dto.enums.AssociatedEntityTypeEnum, actual value: java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution I found from one of the SO answers

```
Properties params = new Properties();
        params.put("enumClass", "models.IOStatusEnum");
        params.put("type", "12"); /*type 12 instructs to use the String representation of enum value*/
        Type myEnumType = new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver()).custom(EnumType.class, params);
        SQLQuery q = sess.createSQLQuery(queryString).addScalar("status", myEnumType);;
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout how to create enum handler and specify over the field like here

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Java5StringValuedEnumUserType?_sscc=t